# How to add blur effect on status bar in iOS 11 correctly without warnings?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, statusbar

I used to add blur effect on status bar with following code:

```
// Add blur effect on status bar
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
blurEffectView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
blurEffectView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
blurEffectView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
blurEffectView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

It works since Xcode 6 or 7, even for Xcode 9. However, the last two lines start to give warning since Xcode 9:

```
'topLayoutGuide' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
```

By following the warning, if I change `topLayoutGuide` to the suggested value, the result is not right (all screen is blank).

How to add blur effect on status bar in iOS 11 correctly without warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
blurEffectView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
blurEffectView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
blurEffectView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
blurEffectView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```